# How to pass form data via controller with Spring MVC 3.1 - new to Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to spring, as well as spring mvc. I'm using version 3.1. Also, for now, I'm using Tomcat 7 and MySQL 5.5. I have data in a database table which I can display on a web page. Now, I'm trying to add data to my database from a web form, and then display that data on a web page.

**Here is part of my runtime error when I try to invoke my web form:**

** Root cause is: Request method 'GET' not supported org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodResolver.resolveHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:665) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:431) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at

**Here is the section of my controller in question**. Note, if I just have the @RequestMapping("/newProfile") line, instead of the other @RequestMapping line, then I get a web page, without my data showing, which is what I would expect, since I haven't plugged in my DAO layer just yet.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newProfile", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
//@RequestMapping("/newProfile")
public String addNewProfile(@ModelAttribute("profile")Profile profile, ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("firstName", profile.getFirstName());
      model.addAttribute("lastName", profile.getLastName());
      return "newProfileResult";
   }
```

**Here is my input web form (using JSP for the moment):**

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Profile Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/newProfile">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>  
</form:form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exception tells that Spring can't find a mapping for a GET request. I assume you enter just /newProfile into your browser. This causes a GET request. Provide a mapping to the GET request. You could do this by a separate mapping, or as you wrote ommit the method.